# Invalid date exception is raised after using thread concept in C# even if the date is valid

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Login loginObject = new Login();          
            int _loginTime = loginObject.login();
            Booking bookingObject = new Booking();
            bookingObject.booking(_loginTime);
            new Thread(delegate()
            {
                bookingObject.booking(_loginTime);
            }).Start();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

 class Booking
    {
       public void booking(int _loginTime)
        {
            DateTime _date;
            int _route;
            int _option;
            string _pan;
            try
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Enter Date of journey(dd/mm/yyyy)");
                _date = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
               //Code here
             }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid date.");
            }
        }
}
```

If I don't use thread, it works fine.But gives "Invalid date" exception if I use thread,even if the date entered is in correct format.
Please provide solution.

Comment: Try to use DateTime.ParseExact with format parameter instead of Convert.ToDateTime. You might also want to check the exception details for additional details of the exception

Comment: Probably the Console.Readline in main is called before the Console.ReadLine in the thread delegate. You could prove it adding some WriteLine to write the output and the current position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not related to parsing, I just tested your code, remove the Console.ReadLine from your main thread, instead of that use Thread.Join to stop the main thread till the spawned thread returns, check the code below, it works as expected:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Login loginObject = new Login();

            //int _loginTime = loginObject.login(); 

            int logintime = 5;

            Booking bookingObject = new Booking();

            bookingObject.booking(logintime);

            Thread t = new Thread(delegate() { bookingObject.booking(logintime); });

            t.Start();

            t.Join();

            //Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Booking
    {
        public void booking(int logintime)
        {
            DateTime _date; 
            int _route; 
            int _option; 
            string _pan; 

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Date of journey(dd/mm/yyyy)");
                string str = Console.ReadLine();
                _date = Convert.ToDateTime(str);


                //_date = DateTime.Parse(str);
                //Code here
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid date.");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception Returns");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In fact what happens is apparently main thread access the same console object and what would be received as an input to the DateTime.Parse function is actually a key press instead of date string and hence the exception, try it out

Answer (score 1):

Probably your main thread current culture differs from the default system culture. When new thread is created in the .NET Framework 4 and previous versions, by default, the culture of all threads is set to the Windows system culture.

So you can use **DateTime.ParseExact** and specify date format explicitly.

Comment: How would the main thread culture differ, until and unless explicitly specified in the code. Even if the culture differs that would be seen in the date parse with a different result than expected it will not lead to Format exception. Also here main thread call is successful but issue is in spawning the thread, any thread spwaned from main thread will have same culture until and unless explicitly specified

Comment: Default culture of any thread is Windows system culture. Please check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). `Convert.ToDateTime` is culture specific and uses current culture of the thread. Because of this invalid culture can be the reason of the problem.

Comment: Did you even tried to understand the comment, let me help:

- Where's explicit thread culture set in this code? point out.

- Why would different culture lead to exception, it would be just different result, different format. Provide example.

In windows everything works on thread, so in any case configurable properties always apply to the code executing on thread, this is from beginning, there's nothing new in it.

Answer (score 1):

When your code reaches the `Thread.Start` it doesn't executes immediately the delegate but continues and reaches the `Console.Readline` in the main method. At this point the system starts the Thread delegate but the first input goes the the `Console.ReadLine` in the main thread.
The subsequent `Console.ReadLine` is the one used in your thread and converted to a date.

You could try this modified version of your code....

```
static AutoResetEvent are = null;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Booking bookingObject = new Booking();
    Console.WriteLine("First call to booking in Main");
    bookingObject.booking(100);

    new Thread(delegate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread starting");
        bookingObject.booking(100);
    }).Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Console.Readline in Main");

    // Comment these two lines to reproduce the original behavior
    are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    are.WaitOne();

    string s = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Result from main readline" + s);
}

class Booking
{
   public void booking(int _loginTime)
   {
        DateTime _date;
        int _route;
        int _option;
        string _pan;
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Date of journey(dd/mm/yyyy)");
            string s = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("User input catched inside the thread: " + s);
            _date = Convert.ToDateTime(s);
            if(are != null) are.Set();
         }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid date.");
        }
    }
}
```

Of course the advice to use a more robust conversion code when the input is not in your control is still perfectly valid. `DateTime.TryParse` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` should be used

Comment: idea remains same, main thread need to be waited using correct mechanism not ReadLine, that's the main reason of this issue, whether Wait Signal (Auto Reset / Manual Reset) or the simple join.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj exactly. The Console Read/Write are still in place to show a simplicistic trace of the code flow with and without the AutoResetEvent kicking its synchronization